# How to setup an open (No Password) Wi-Fi Hotspot in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

I have successfully setup a Wi-Fi Hotspot in Ubuntu 18.
But I want it to be open to everyone, no passwords required.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

once you have activated Hotspot..

run the command `nm-connection-editor`

and edit the values like below for Wi-Fi Security tab == > Security = None

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Glad to see `nm-connection-editor` still works in Ubuntu 21.04.